# How can I remove certain element types from a raw HTML response?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, wikipedia-api

I am making a request to the wiki API, similar [this request for the Wiki page content on the term 'country'](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Country). I am reading the 'extract' from the response in Typescript/Javascript, and rendering that as HTML on the page of my application.

How can I remove elements from the response?

I would like to remove all < li > objects, and if possible also remove all content AFTER the element with an id of 'Further Reading'.

I am using this to grab the 'extract' section of the JSON:

```
let pageId = Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0];
let page = data['query']['pages'][pageId];
resolve(data['query']['pages'][pageId]['extract']);
```

Here is the function call:

```
this.goWiki().then(result => {
            this.info= result.toString();
        });
```

Here is the HTML render:

```
 <div *ngIf="info" [innerHTML]="info">

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

//this will help you to remove li tag

```
this.info = result.toString.replace(/<li\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/li>/i,"")
```